# FileSystemWatcher throws System.IO.InternalBufferOverflowException in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I created an application in C# that continuously listens to a folder for new file additions, once a new file is added, it picks up that file and uploads it to an S3 bucket. I tested the application out with 4-5 files and it works perfectly fine, but as soon as I added 55 files to that folder, the application threw a "System.IO.InternalBufferOverflowException" error. What can I do to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

I'm thinking to increase the buffer size for FileSystemWatcher, but I'm not too sure if that's the way to go.

This is the code for FileSystemWatcher that I've written in the Home. How can I modify it to enqueue an info object for later processing on a different thread?

```
private async void Home_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    public FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(envFolderLocation);
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Security | NotifyFilters.Size;
    
    watcher.Created += OnCreated;
    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
    watcher.Error += OnError;
    
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

My goal is to avoid this exception altogether and process the files in the folder even if a large number of files are added quickly.

Comment: FSW has a quirk (or one of those): you need to handle the events _quickly_. What I did was to just enqueue an info object for later processing on different thread and nothing else inside the event handlers. If you do too much, events _will_ pile up and finally overflow.

Comment: We can't guess what's wrong with no code. 55 files aren't a lot. If the code takes too long to process messages though, you'd get overflows. Post the code.

Comment: A very easy way to handle notifications *and* uploading is to use an `ActionBlock` or even a pipeline of Dataflow blocks. An ActionBlock uses one or more worker tasks to process messages and do stuff asynchronously. The event handler can post each path or even the entire event argument to the block. The block will read the path from the message and upload it. You can easily upload multiple files concurrently by setting the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` setting of the block to something greater than 1

Comment: Post the code so the question can be opened. The real solution may involve *not* handling any individual events, but calling `TransferUtility.UploadDirectoryAsync` *after* events have stopped appearing for a while. There's no `Close` event so if you try to process events immediately you may find that the file is still locked for copying.

Comment: Could you give us an idea what kind of code runs in the `OnCreated` and `OnChanged` handlers? Are you doing heavy lifting inside these handlers?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [InternalBufferOverflowException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.internalbufferoverflowexception) states

> In a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher), when you are notified of file changes, the system stores those changes in a buffer the component creates and passes to the Application Programming Interfaces (APIs). If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can easily overflow, resulting in an exception being thrown, which essentially loses all changes. To keep the buffer from overflowing, use the [FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter) and [FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories) properties to filter out your unwanted change notifications. You can also increase the size of the internal buffer through the [FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize) property. However, increasing the size of the buffer is expensive, so keep the buffer as small as possible.

So there are several remedies that you can try, and, most likely, you will need to apply some combination thereof.

1. The first set you should try is filtering using the `NotifyFilter` and `IncludeSubdirectories` properties. These directly affect the number of events and scope of what you need to look at, so these should be tried first. You probably care more about new files being complete`*` and created (for example) than changes in file attributes and security.
2. Because event processing is sequential and limited to the internal buffer, and because *what* you do for each event is inline, you can offload it. Fildor suggests this in the comment to your post. This is a good second line of defense. My suggestion is to use a `ConcurrentQueue` and a background thread or task that dequeues and works on the events.
3. Finally, you can increase the buffer size as noted in the documentation. You can follow the link to `InternalBufferSize` for the reason they state it is expensive. It doesn't "feel" like the right solution though; it's more likely just going to lead to the problem again with an even larger change set.

FWIW, there is an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14645) on GitHub (since 2015!) to add event buffering. This is akin to point #2 above.

`*` Complete is something the FSW can't convey by the way. What does complete mean? The only way to really solve this problem from a watcher point of view is to use a heuristic, such as the last modification occuring some time ago like 5 seconds. But even that is fraught with peril (thanks
Panagiotis for the reminder).

Comment: It's an application bug, not an FSW bug. Contrary to what the reporter says, it *is* the application's job to process such messages quickly. Otherwise the application may end up trying to eg process a creation event *after* the file was deleted

Comment: Agreed, but that doesn't mean thise question can't be answered. I've worked for a storage networking company, and "that's the way it is" can't possibly be a good answer.

Comment: And I've built a Dropbox clone that handled GB-sized files. I know the OP is going to run into weird events once the files get bigger. FSW isn't a new component, it works this way since the VB Classic days. That behavior is well known, expected and handled, by having another worker handle the events. That "issue" has a lot of unrelated comments that people mistakenly think are related to buffering, when in fact they have to do with whether the *file system* reports changes or not.

Comment: Never mind that "changes" isn't what people think - it only refers to attribute and size changes. The OP is going to find out there's no `close` notification and the files may be locked for copying. And since Explorer (and many apps like Word) preallocate the full file size, there may only be a single change event even for a large file

Comment: The real solution ... doesn't exist. The real solution would be to take advantage of NTFS journaling and snapshots, which just aren't accessible through .NET. Unlike Linux, journaling and snapshots have to be enabled at the volume (not folder) level and require admin rights. One would have to use Win32 API calls or a library like [AlphaFS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS/) in .NET Framework.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I agree with you. For the average case like file uploads there are mitigations that help. Yes, the FSW is a total dinosaur. Things like alternate filestreams, antivirus checkers hooking calls, and cloud storage makes a one-size fits all solution virtually impossible.